# Pandas cummax datetime when NaT values exist

Tags: python, max

I have a column of "Purchase Dates".
The column either contains NaT or an actual date.

```
Date        Last_Purchase Cummax_Purchase
2010-05-28             NaT           NaT
2010-06-01      2010-06-01    2010-06-01
2010-06-02      2010-06-02    2010-06-02
2010-06-03             NaT           NaT
2010-06-04             NaT           NaT
```

I want to do a cummax() on the column such that it returns the most recent purchase date.

```
    data['Purchase_Date'] = numpy.where(data['Buy Signal'] == True, data.index.astype(str), pandas.NaT)  
    data['Cummax_Purchase'] = pandas.to_datetime(data['Purchase_Date']).cummax()
```

The above cummax returns an NaT whenever their is an NaT in a corresponding row, not the cummax.
But whenever I change the pandas.NaT to 0, then it works. But I want to return NaT values when there is an NaT.

Any advice?

EDIT: here's a small sample code:

```
data = pandas.DataFrame(
{"Purchase Dates" : pandas.to_datetime(['01-01-2020', '02-01-2020',None,'04-01-2020'])}, index=pandas.to_datetime(['01-01-2020','02-01-2020','03-01-2020','04-01-2020']))
data['Cummax_date'] = df['Purchase Dates'].cummax()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you do not provide a fully runnable example (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which makes it a bit hard to answer. Here is an attempt nevertheless assuming that data is a `pd.DataFrame`:

```
mask = ~data['Purchase Dates'].isna()
data.loc[mask, 'Cummax_Purchase'] = data.loc[mask, 'Purchase Dates'].cummax()
```

Essentially, the approach is to run `cummax()` only on the part of the data that is actually a value and not on the `NaT`s

EDIT:
After a clarification on the requirements, the solution is:

```
data['Cummax_date'] = data['Purchase Dates'].ffill()
```

If the purchase dates are not in order, they have to be sorted first

Comment: Thanks, I added a small sample code to the bottom of my original post. Problem is, when you run it, I can't get the '2020-03-01' date to show the cummax. I tried your code as well and it still shows NaT. Basically, I'm trying to display all rows in the dataframe, but just show the previous max date when there is a corresponding NaT.

Comment: Your code example is not runnable, but I assume that you meant `data` in the second row instead of `df`. And with your additional explanation, I guess that what you want is:
`data['Cummax_date'] = data['Purchase Dates'].ffill()` (assuming that your Purchase dates are in order. Otherwise you would have to sort them first

Comment: Perfect. Feel free to accept the answer to close the question